# Excel Function - How to correctly format this IF AND query

Tags: excel

I can't seem to make this IF function work with multiple conditions. Does anybody know how to format this query correctly?

if A1 = "Hat" AND B1 = "1" return "5" if A1 = "Hat" AND B1 = "2" return "10"
if A1 = "Glove" AND B1 = "1" return "15" if A1 = "Glove" AND B1 = "2" return "20"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
=IF(A1="hat";IF(B1=1;5;IF(B1=2;10;""));IF(A1="glove";IF(B1=1;15;IF(B1=2;20));""))
```